# How can I SpyOn injected service with @Inject

Tags: angular

I'm working with different services based on the environment. I want to mock values on some methods but it is not working as expected:

I have an interface named CategoryService with a method.

Then I have an implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class MockCategoryService implements CategoryService {

  CATEGORIES: Category[] = [{ id: 1, name: 'Food' }, { id: 2, name: 'Rent' }]

  public getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return of(this.CATEGORIES);
  }
}
```

And in my environment file I have this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  categoryService: MockCategoryService
};
```

Then, in a component test that is using this service I can not make a spyOn on it.

Component constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject('CategoryService') private categoryService: CategoryService) { }
```

And my test configuration:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ExpensesLayoutComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'CategoryService', useClass: MockCategoryService
        },
        MockCategoryService
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockCategoryService = TestBed.inject(MockCategoryService);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExpensesLayoutComponent);
    spyOn(mockCategoryService, 'getCategories').and.returnValue(of([{ id: 1, name: 'category01' }]))
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

getCategories method is returning the mocked values in the services instead of returning the values I want to use when I perform the spyOn over mockCategoryService.
Something is wrong here but I do not know how to do it.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you're registering two providers that will instantiate two separate instances of `MockCategoryService`.

### Option 1

String tokens are deprecated in Angular DI but if you really want to use `'CategoryService'` as a token then you can retrieve it via:

```
mockCategoryService = TestBed.inject<CategoryService>('CategoryService' as any);
```

### Option 2

You can convert `CategoryService` into an abstract class and use it directly without `@Inject`

### Option 3

You can use `InjectionToken`:

```
export const CATEGORY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<CategoryService>('CategoryService');
```

then provide it like:

```
provide: CATEGORY_SERVICE, useClass: MockCategoryService
```

Component constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(CATEGORY_SERVICE) private categoryService: CategoryService) { }
```

and the accessor will be like:

```
mockCategoryService = TestBed.inject(CATEGORY_SERVICE);
```

### Option 4

Replace `useClass` with `useExisting` in providers:

```
provide: 'CategoryService', useExisting: MockCategoryService
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I was trying by myself option 3 but I had some lack of knowledge that you answer has filled.